# Using `kill -s 0 $pid` vs `[[ -e /proc/$pid ]]` to detect if PID is running

Tags: linux, shell-script, process, kill, process-management

One of the idioms often used to check if process is running is to use `kill -s 0 $pid`.

My question is, does it have any upsides over using `[[ -e /proc/$pid ]]` construct?

The script I'm writing is both Linux and bash specific.

Comment: This is not a sufficient test: the process may exist, and may even belong to you, but it may already be _different_ from the one you were interested in -- Unix reuses PIDs, obviously. Once you establish, the process still exists, you also need to check the process' start time...

Comment: @MikhailT. yes, there's the whole issue of TOCTOU, as was pointed out in the discussions on answers, but that's not what the question is about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would prefer `kill -s 0 pid` vs testing `/proc/pid` as the former is portable, being specified by POSIX. Even if your script is targeting Linux, there is still a (very slight) risk for `/proc` to be unmounted for some reason.

Comment: While the portability argument is moot as the script is Linux specific and won't be ported to other Unices (for one, it interfaces with kernel using `/sys` already). The possibility for `/proc` being unmounted is valid, even if unlikely. So I'm marking this answer as the accepted one.

Comment: I generally agree that `kill -s 0 pid` is the right way to go, but note that there are cases where it's not appropriate. Primarily when you don't have permissions to signal the process (non-root or whatnot).

Comment: @Patrick, I agree about the privilege requirement issue. I guess though that when someone test if a process is running, he usually has the privilege to restart it which means either the process belongs to him or he is root.

Comment: Neither of these methods tell you whether there is such a process, only whether or not there were such a process at the instant in the past when you performed the test.

Comment: @Johan That looks to me more a philosophical point than a technical one. Anything you do/test/observe is instantly moved in the past anyway.

Comment: @jlliagre It depends on how paranoid you are.  Or realy on how important your production application is.  I once wrote a "kill script" for operators on production systems which would first send a STOP signal, then check that the process they are targeting is still the one the operator intend on killing, and then finally send a TERM or KILL signal.

Answer (score 2):

I would generally use a command such as `kill` over reading content directly from `/proc`. The upside is that a tool such as `kill` will return status codes (think `$?`) if it was successful, or not, and should in theory already have any API related things included, when it's dealing with `/proc` content vs. rolling it yourself.

Additionally using dedicated commands makes for better portability of your code across the various Unixes. `/proc` is not ubiquitous on other Unixes such as Solaris and AIX.

#### Examples

Test process to kill.

```
$ sleep 10 &
[1] 11639
```

Now we kill it.

```
$ kill 11639
[1]+  Terminated              sleep 10
```

Were we successful?

```
$ echo $?
0
```

A zero means we were successful. Anything else, we could handle it in different ways. With reading the `/proc` directly, we're left in a bit of a quandary.

Same situation, we're attempting to kill a non-existent process.

```
$ kill 61234
bash: kill: (61234) - No such process
```

We get feedback about it.

```
$ echo $?
1
```

#### What else?

You may also want to investigate using `pkill` and `pgrep` too if you'd rather kill or look for a process by name, rather than `$pid`. But it depends ultimately on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Well, `[[ -e /proc/pid ]]` also returns a status code, after all.

Comment: @ChrisDown - true, but I would expect a much richer range of statuses using `kill` vs. reading `/proc` is my general point.

Comment: @slm, the expected status doesn't need to be anything but `true` or `false` (and perhaps `permission denied` in restrictive environments). You might be missing the `-s 0` part of the question which is not about killing a process but just testing its presence.

Comment: @jlliagre - yes I should've mentioned that I was aware of `kill -0 ..`. That still doesn't change which method would be the more appropriate to use.

Answer (score 1):

There is a major difference between `kill -s 0 $pid` and `[ -e /proc/$pid ]`. The latter tests whether there is a process (or zombie) with this PID. The former only matches processes (or zombies) to which you can send a signal, i.e. the process's real or saved UID must be the same as the UID of the shell you're running this from (unless the shell is running as root, in which case there is no difference).

Which one to use depends on whether you want to match other users' processes.

`kill -s 0 $pid` is very portable (it's POSIX-compliant). Testing for `/proc/$pid` doesn't work on BSD unices as they don't have `/proc`; a portable way of achieving the same effect is `ps -p $pid >/dev/null 2>/dev/null`.

Comment: Yet, on linux ps would go straight ahead to querying /proc/$pid so one may as well save the overhead of forking a whole new process.

Comment: @user16653: One: `ps` is a tool to be used by user, not in scripts, querying `/proc` in such use case and being racy is not a problem. Two: `kill` is a bash builtin, there is no forking involved in either command.